# How do I update a csv file daily in python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to minimize the amount of data I get in a day, so it would be nice if I could save all the data except for today's data in a CSV file and just add today's data to it!
This (the image) does not reflect the date and there is a discrepancy.
If this could be fixed, it would be perfect!
[image: your image description goes here]

So, if there is a good way to write a day's worth of data directly into a csv by date, please let me know. If not, please let me know how to put the csv back into a dataframe and then connect the dataframes together and overwrite the csv.
( i use a mac)

Comment: Hi. This is certainly possible. Have a look at the Pandas library. The pandas.DataFrame.to_csv method allows you to export a DataFrame to a .csv file directly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you could upload some of the code you have used in an edit we could help you quicker.

It looks like you are just updating your dataframe into the wrong columns. Instead of populating from column 2-6 you are populating into 1-5.

You could use a simple date function to populate the first cell in the first column:

`from datetime import datetime`

`datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`